# CSS Design problems in product view page if attribute value = “NO”

Tags: magento

we are using magento site. we created an attribute "Cash on delivery"

in product page , we are displaying "cash on delivery is available or not" using attribute values

attribute value = "yes " = > http://site1.com/peacock-feathers-xiaomi-redmi-1s-phone-case.html

Attribute value = "No" = > http://site1.com/peacock-feathers-xiaomi-mi3-phone-case.html

if we gave value " NO", than design problems are happening in above link.

1)DELIVERED BY Block is displaying below.

2)Horizontal lines are missing above : "Key Feature" text.

3)Font-size is different for "Key feature"

[image]

complete code of the page : http://pastebin.com/HNH6uyHw

```
<div class="Quick_2">

<!-- Sold By -->
<div class="soled_by">
<?php 
 $helper=Mage::helper('marketplace');
                        $_product=Mage::registry('current_product');
                        $productowner=Mage::getModel('marketplace/product')->isCustomerProduct($_product['entity_id']);
                        if($productowner['userid']!=""){
                        $captchenable = $percent = Mage::getStoreConfig('marketplace/marketplace_options/captcha');
                    $rowsocial=Mage::getModel('marketplace/userprofile')->getPartnerProfileById($productowner['userid']);
                    }   
                    ?>                       
 <script type="text/javascript">
 if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined'){
document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
 }
 </script> 



<div class="soled-by-dealer">
<!--<div class="block-title"><strong><span>
 <?php   if($rowsocial['shoptitle']!='')
 echo $rowsocial['shoptitle'];
 else
 echo  $rowsocial['profileurl']; ?>
 </span></strong>
 </div>-->

<h5> SOLD BY : </h5>

<span>                       


 <?php if($rowsocial['profileurl'] == "kidsdial2")
  {?>

 <a href="<?php echo  Mage::getUrl('marketplace/seller/collection').$rowsocial['profileurl'] ?>" title="<?php echo "sitename"; ?>" id="siteconnect">
  <?php echo "sitename"; ?></a><?php

   }

  else{?>

 <a href="<?php echo  Mage::getUrl('marketplace/seller/collection').$rowsocial['profileurl'] ?>" title="<?php echo $rowsocial['profileurl']; ?>" id="siteconnect">
  <?php echo $rowsocial['profileurl']; ?></a><?php 
  }

 ?>
 </span>        

</div>
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: will you please post the code part inside your div with class Quick_2 ?

Comment: @Enigmativity if we set the attribute value= 
"no", than design problems are happening. i want this link  http://videomergerapp.com/peacock-feathers-xiaomi-mi3-phone-case.html should look like http://videomergerapp.com/peacock-feathers-xiaomi-redmi-1s-phone-case.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would you please replace your div `delivery_details` with this code below.

```
<div class="delivery_details">


                    <div class="COD">
                    <?php $attribute = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('cod_available');
                        $attribute_value = $attribute ->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);

                            if ($attribute_value == "Yes"){ ?>
                                <h5> CASH ON DELIVERY </h5>       
                                <div class="Delivery_hover_details">?<p class="killing"><?php echo "Available";?></p></div>
                            <?php }else{ ?>
                                  <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
                                  <p>
                                    <h5> CASH ON DELIVERY </h5>
                                    <?php echo " Not Available"; ?>
                                  </p>
                                  <?php } ?>
                               <span class="coupontooltip">
                                   <div class="cod_content">
                                       <h5>How do I place a Cash on Delivery (COD) order?</h5>
                                        <p>All items that have the "Cash on Delivery Available" icon are valid for order by Cash on Delivery.</p>
                                        <p>Add the item(s) to your cart and proceed to checkout.When prompted to choose a payment option, select "Cash on Delivery". </p>
                                        <p>Once you place the order you will receive confirmation call from our customer support for validation with in 48 hours. Once verified and confirmed, your order will be processed for shipment in the time specified, from the date of confirmation. You will be required to make a cash-only payment to our courier partner at the time of delivery of your order to complete the payment.</p>
                                        <p>Terms & Conditions</p>
                                        <p>The maximum order value for COD is ₹5000.</p>
                                        <p>e-Gift Vouchers or Store Credit cannot be used for COD orders.</p>
                                        <p>Cash-only payment at the time of delivery.</p>
                                    </div>
                                </span>

                            </div>
```

You have missed to close a div inside a condition. and this must work now.

Comment: i just have made changes, please do again and feedback me

Comment: once iremoved the extra <div> , it started to work, thanks al ot for your support